# How to create a list of system packages with their description?

Tags: nixos, nix

I need to create a file with the list of all packages installed system-wide.

I can see in the repl that `pname` and `meta` are available for each package

```
nix-repl> emacs.pname
"emacs"

nix-repl> emacs.meta.description
"The extensible, customizable GNU text editor"
```

When I'm trying to do the following in `configuration.nix`, `p` is of type `path` instead of `set` and does not have properties such as `pname` and `meta`.

```
  environment.etc."packages".text = with lib;
    builtins.concatStringsSep "\n" (builtins.sort builtins.lessThan (lib.unique
      (builtins.map (
            p: "${p.pname} ${p.meta.description}"
      ) config.environment.systemPackages)));
```

How can I get both package name and description in `/etc/packages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lib.getName` to get the name for a derivation.

All packages should have a `meta` attribute. You may have seen `description` missing for some packages. You can use `p.meta.description or "(none)"` to handle those cases.

Putting it together, you get:

```
{
  environment.etc."packages".text = with lib;
    builtins.concatStringsSep "\n" (builtins.sort builtins.lessThan (lib.unique
      (builtins.map (
            p: "${getName p} ${p.meta.description or "(none)"}"
      ) config.environment.systemPackages)));
}
```

Comment: this does not work, `p` has no `meta` attribute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It worked on my system and generated a complete list. Which package are you finding lacks `meta`? In any case, you can use an `or` clause to guard against a missing `meta` attribute. You can also use `nix repl` to play with different expressions more rapidly.